# HTML divs over another

Tags: html, position, z-index

I tried one of the suggestion given by SOF but did not work.  I'm trying to make a context menu which I have the menu item over a gray band at the left.  Here's the code but even with z-index to 10 my menu items appears below.  Anyone have a trick to put the menu items over the band without too much effort and changes ?

```
<div id="ContextMenu">
<div id="IContextOverlay" style="z-index:-1;position:absolute;background:gray;opacity:.5;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
<div id="IContext" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;z-index:1;background:GhostWhite;border:1px solid black;width:300px;height:400px;box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px">
    <div id="IBand" style="height:400px;z-index:0;width:32px;background:#dbdbdb;border:0 1px 1px 0 solid black"></div>
    <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px;" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/attachdocument.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_SendAttachment" class="ContextMenuText">Send attachment</a>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/viewattachment.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_ViewDocument" class="ContextMenuText">View document</a>
    </div>

    <div style="z-index:10;border-top:1px solid black;width:95%;margin-left:5px;"></div>

    <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/Copy.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_Copy" class="ContextMenuText">Copy</a>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/Delete.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_Delete" class="ContextMenuText">Delete</a>
    </div>

    <div style="z-index:10;border-top:1px solid black;width:95%;margin-left:5px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why but the code I paste isn't shown correctly but when I edit it the code is all there and correct.  The last div isn't there and the ContextMenu div content isn't indented sorry about that.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/z9Let18x/1/

Comment: I finally decided to use a gradient which do a great job for less

Answer (score 1):

> well, you need to wrap your `content` inside `div` and in the parent
>   `div` give style `display:inline-flex;`

here is your code:

```html
<div id="ContextMenu">
  <div id="IContextOverlay" style="z-index:-1;position:absolute;background:gray;opacity:.5;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
  <div id="IContext" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;z-index:1;background:GhostWhite;border:1px solid black;width:300px;height:400px;box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px; display:inline-flex; ">
    <div id="IBand" style="height:400px;z-index:0;width:32px;background:#dbdbdb;border:0 1px 1px 0 solid black"></div>
    <div>
      <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px;" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/attachdocument.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_SendAttachment" class="ContextMenuText">Send attachment</a>
      </div>
      <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/viewattachment.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_ViewDocument" class="ContextMenuText">View document</a>
      </div>

      <div style="z-index:10;border-top:1px solid black;width:95%;margin-left:5px;"></div>

      <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/Copy.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_Copy" class="ContextMenuText">Copy</a>
      </div>
      <div style="z-index:10;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;height:22px" class="menuItemRowSelection">
        <img src="/Images/Delete.png" width="20" style="float:left" />
        <a id="menuItem_Delete" class="ContextMenuText">Delete</a>
      </div>

      <div style="z-index:10;border-top:1px solid black;width:95%;margin-left:5px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Also it will be easier to figure out any problems if you do the
>   styling in separate sheet or in header, Or if you want to apply your
>   style to another content.
>
> By the way I don't think you need to `z-index`.

**Iet me know if you have any question.**

Comment: I just tried and it's the same result.  Here's the new code :

Comment: I finally decided to use a gradient which do a great job for less

Comment: You should add it as an answer...!